# Steps to digitize OpenStreetMap in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-plugins, digitizing

I am new to QGIS.

Can someone help me with the steps to digitize `OpenStreetMap`?

Or should I save the particular area I want to digitize into `.tiff` files and then try to digitize the `.tiff` file?

Answer (score 10):

There is no need to manually digitize all the `OSM` Maps. According to the OSM website

> OpenStreetMap is a map of the world, created by people like you and free to use under an open license.

So you are able to use the underlying data in all the maps,
Simply download what you want to use, following the steps in [this](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/downloading_osm_data.html) guide or [this](http://learnosm.org/en/osm-data/osm-in-qgis/) one.

Comment: if you want to download all vector files that you needed, you can do it via geofabrik (http://download.geofabrik.de/) , then you can sort it out later (depends on what you need)

Comment: Can I get DEM from OpenStreetMap ?

Comment: You can download the ASTER DEM using the links provided [here](https://asterweb.jpl.nasa.gov/gdem.asp)